# how to return a 403 status code on apicontroller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I want to keep my return type as a string but want the response code to be a 403.

This is what I currently have.

```
[HttpGet]
public string test(string echoText)
{
    // Not authorized
    if (echoText == "403")
    {
        StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        return "";
    }
    else
        return echoText;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I found the below code but is there another way without throwing an exception?

```
throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could throw a `HttpResponseException` inside your action:

```
[HttpGet]
public string test(string echoText)
{
    // Not authorized
    if (echoText == "403")
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
    }
    else
        return echoText;
}
```

Comment: I just updated my questions about 2 seconds before your post :)

Comment: Didn't see your update, sorry! I do not believe you have alternatives if you want to keep your return type a string.